# React Webpack Boilerplate for Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, react

Somebody suggested that I not use Truffle if i want to go into production mode. Is there a React Webpack boilerplate for Blockchain? If so, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle performs a different role to React. Truffle handles interaction with contracts on a blockchain, whereas React is a user interaction framework. So you can't replace Truffle with React. You may well want to use both Truffle and React in your application.

There's no particular problem using Truffle in production. The comment you heard may have referred to the build system: Truffle provides a default build system for creating a web application that talks to your contracts, but it's a bit primitive. See here for how to use a different build system: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/bundling-with-webpack